# Some Items in System Settings are duplicated, how can I fix it?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, gui, .desktop, system-settings

Once I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 some of the items in System Settings have been duplicated for some reason, anyone got a fix?

[image: Screenshot Of Bug]

Comment: what is the output of (e.g.) `find /usr/share/applications -name *appear*` (run in a terminal window)

Comment: @JacobVlijm /usr/share/applications/unity-appearance-panel.desktop
/usr/share/applications/unity-appearance-panel.desktop~
/usr/share/applications/unity-appearance-panel (copy).desktop~
/usr/share/applications/settings/unity-appearance-panel.desktop

Comment: In 16.04, only `/usr/share/applications/unity-appearance-panel.desktop` should be there. Could you move the others to trash, log out/in and see if it is fixed for Appearance? I guess you upgraded from an earlier Ubuntu version? Also, it seems you manually edited the `.desktop` file with `gedit`, right? Looking at the ~ backup files,

Comment: Hi the Appearance menu dupe was removed,  I managed to find the duplicates and delete them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Duplicated launchers cause duplicated icons

System settings is populated by `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`, representing the different settings options.

Almost certainly, the duplicate icons are the result of duplicated versions of these `.desktop` files. Most likely the old `.desktop` files remained somehow after an upgrade from an earlier Ubuntu version. New versions will have slightly different names.

#### What to do

To find out, run

```
find /usr/share/applications -name *appear*.
```

...to find duplicates of the `apperance`' `.desktop` file.

In case of multiple files, keep the newest, remove the older ones. Subsequently log out and back in.

Repeat the procedure for all duplicated entries in the settings window, and it should be fixed.