# Recover usual System Settings page

Tags: system-settings

Somehow my System Settings page turned into this:

[image: My messed up system settings page]

Some icons are duplicated as you can see.
It happened after I installed and removed some applets for the panel but I can't trace back the root cause of the problem.

It would be great if I could have my old System Settings page back which looked like this:

[image: How it used to look example]

I found this answer and a few similar to this: 
 [Some Items in System Settings are duplicated, how can I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806600/some-items-in-system-settings-are-duplicated-how-can-i-fix-it)

But is that really the only way to "roll back"? And I am not certain if this is exactly the same problem, e.g. i used to have a search bar without the need to click a button and the background was grey. Also the applications seem to be kind of "different". Maybe it's some old version of the system settings page?

I tried to reinstall `gnome-control-center` but it didn't had any effect.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after posting this i found the solution:
the messed up system settings page was caused by the gnome-control-center. When I tried to remove the `gnome-control-center`, my system automatically installed `unity-control-center` again which is working fine.

The reason why I didn't think of this in the first place is because I'm not using Unity but Gnome.